# Should I convert my dynamic urls for SEO?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm currently reading the book "Professional Search Engine Optimization with PHP: A Developer's Guide to SEO". In it, it refers to dynamic URL having a negative effect on SEO. That being said, I have some dynamic URLs that look like:

```
http://example.com/schedule/?day=monday
http://example.com/schedule/?day=tuesday
http://example.com/schedule/?day=wednesday
```

Given I am only using one parameter, are the above URLs having a negative effect on the SEO?

Is it worth it to use mod_rewrite to change the link structure? Example:

```
http://example.com/schedule/monday
```

I have quite a few of these types of dynamic URLs, but they all only have one parameter.

Should I go through the trouble of re-writing the URLs?

Comment: Short Answer : **YES**

Comment: Short Answer: **NO** (More seriously, this is very subjective, depends on how much work it would be for you, how important SEO actually is for you, how much impact changing the URLs like that actually has in the secret algorithms used by search engines and probably several other factors).

Comment: It depends very much on what you want. For example, the pagination is not necessary to rewrite it. Example: url `http://example.com/schedules?page=1` in my opinion is better then `http://example.com/schedules/page1`.

Comment: I would say that yes it would be worth the effort in rewriting things as it makes the website overall look that much neater and more professional. It really isnt that much work to create an apache based router with htaccess either (unless your website is like HuGE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am only using one parameter, are the above URLs having a negative
>   effect on the SEO?
>   Is it worth it to use mod_rewrite to change the link structure?

I think it will have a negative effect on the SEO. And it is worth it to use mod_rewrite to change the link structure. If you want a fully search engine optimized content that is worth it.

Comment: Here is a great tutorial on rewriting URLS: http://moz.com/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls - As a super sidenote but while we are on the subject of search engines... Saw in the news today that google will rank lower websites that do not use SSL!